# How to implement the repetition of objects

Tags: java, libgdx

How to implement Actor repetition and update it from time to time.In 0 seconds, laser 1 is in the initial position. In 1 second already 2 laser where 1 shifted and the second (which a new took the place of 1 which was in 0 seconds).In 3 seconds, 1 has already moved to two positions,the second took the position of 1 laser in 1 second and 3 laser at the very end(in the position of the first laser in 0 second)

class laser

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

  public class Laser extends BaseActor {

public Laser(float x, float y, Stage s) {
    super(x, y, s);
    loadTexture("assets/Line11.png");

    setSize(30,10);
    setMaxSpeed(800);
    setBoundaryPolygon(8);
    setSpeed(10);
}

   public void act(float dt) {
    super.act(dt);
    applyPhysics(dt);

}
}
```

class BaseActor

```
   /**
  * Extends functionality of the LibGDX Actor class.
  * by adding support for textures/animation, 
   * collision polygons, movement, world boundaries, and camera scrolling. 
   * Most game objects should extend this class; lists of extensions can be retrieved by stage and 
   class name.
   * @see #Actor
    * @author Lee Stemkoski
    */
 public class BaseActor extends Group
{
private Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
private float elapsedTime;
private boolean animationPaused;

private Vector2 velocityVec;
private  Vector2 velocityVecY;
private Vector2 accelerationVec;
private float acceleration;
private float maxSpeed;
private float deceleration;


private Polygon boundaryPolygon;

// stores size of game world for all actors
private static Rectangle worldBounds;

public BaseActor(float x, float y, Stage s)
{
    // call constructor from Actor class
    super();

    // perform additional initialization tasks
    setPosition(x,y);
    s.addActor(this);

    // initialize animation data
    animation = null;
    elapsedTime = 0;
    animationPaused = false;

    // initialize physics data
    velocityVec = new Vector2(0,0);
    velocityVecY=new Vector2(0,0);
    accelerationVec = new Vector2(0,0);
    acceleration = 0;
    maxSpeed = 1000;
    deceleration = 0;

    boundaryPolygon = null;
}



/** 
 *  If this object moves completely past the world bounds,
 *  adjust its position to the opposite side of the world.
 */
public void wrapAroundWorld()
{
    if (getX() + getWidth() < 0)
        setX( worldBounds.width );

    if (getX() > worldBounds.width)    
        setX( -getWidth());

    if (getY() + getHeight() < 0)
        setY( worldBounds.height );

    if (getY() > worldBounds.height)
        setY( -getHeight() );
}

/**
 *  Align center of actor at given position coordinates.
 *  @param x x-coordinate to center at
 *  @param y y-coordinate to center at
 */
public void centerAtPosition(float x, float y)
{

    setPosition( x - getWidth()/2 , y - getHeight()/2 );
}

/** 
 *  Repositions this BaseActor so its center is aligned
 *  with center of other BaseActor. Useful when one BaseActor spawns another.
 *  @param other BaseActor to align this BaseActor with
 */
public void centerAtActor(BaseActor other)
{
    centerAtPosition( other.getX() + other.getWidth()/2 , other.getY() + other.getHeight()/2 );
}

// ----------------------------------------------
// Animation methods
// ----------------------------------------------

/**
 * Sets the animation used when rendering this actor; also sets actor size.
 * @param anim animation that will be drawn when actor is rendered
 */
public void setAnimation(Animation<TextureRegion> anim)
{
    animation = anim;
    TextureRegion tr = animation.getKeyFrame(0);
    float w = tr.getRegionWidth();
    float h = tr.getRegionHeight();
    setSize( w, h );
    setOrigin( w/2, h/2 );

    if (boundaryPolygon == null)
        setBoundaryRectangle();
}

/**
 * Creates an animation from images stored in separate files.
 * @param fileNames array of names of files containing animation images
 * @param frameDuration how long each frame should be displayed
 * @param loop should the animation loop
 * @return animation created (useful for storing multiple animations)
 */
public Animation<TextureRegion> loadAnimationFromFiles(String[] fileNames, float frameDuration, boolean loop)
{ 
    int fileCount = fileNames.length;
    Array<TextureRegion> textureArray = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    for (int n = 0; n < fileCount; n++)
    {   
        String fileName = fileNames[n];
        Texture texture = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal(fileName) );
        texture.setFilter( TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear );
        textureArray.add( new TextureRegion( texture ) );
    }

    Animation<TextureRegion> anim = new Animation<TextureRegion>(frameDuration, textureArray);

    if (loop)
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    else
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);

    if (animation == null)
        setAnimation(anim);

    return anim;
}

/**
 * Creates an animation from a spritesheet: a rectangular grid of images stored in a single file.
 * @param fileName name of file containing spritesheet
 * @param rows number of rows of images in spritesheet
 * @param cols number of columns of images in spritesheet
 * @param frameDuration how long each frame should be displayed
 * @param loop should the animation loop
 * @return animation created (useful for storing multiple animations)
 */
public Animation<TextureRegion> loadAnimationFromSheet(String fileName, int rows, int cols, float frameDuration, boolean loop)
{ 
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileName), true);
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    int frameWidth = texture.getWidth() / cols;
    int frameHeight = texture.getHeight() / rows;

    TextureRegion[][] temp = TextureRegion.split(texture, frameWidth, frameHeight);

    Array<TextureRegion> textureArray = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            textureArray.add( temp[r][c] );

    Animation<TextureRegion> anim = new Animation<TextureRegion>(frameDuration, textureArray);

    if (loop)
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    else
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);

    if (animation == null)
        setAnimation(anim);

    return anim;
}

/**
 *  Convenience method for creating a 1-frame animation from a single texture.
 *  @param fileName names of image file
 *  @return animation created (useful for storing multiple animations)
 */
public Animation<TextureRegion> loadTexture(String fileName)
{
    String[] fileNames = new String[1];
    fileNames[0] = fileName;
    return loadAnimationFromFiles(fileNames, 1, true);
}

/**
 *  Set the pause state of the animation.
 *  @param pause true to pause animation, false to resume animation
 */
public void setAnimationPaused(boolean pause)
{
    animationPaused = pause;
}

/**
 *  Checks if animation is complete: if play mode is normal (not looping)
 *      and elapsed time is greater than time corresponding to last frame.
 *  @return 
 */
public boolean isAnimationFinished()
{
    return animation.isAnimationFinished(elapsedTime);
}

/**
 *  Sets the opacity of this actor.
 *  @param opacity value from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque)
 */
public void setOpacity(float opacity)
{
    this.getColor().a = opacity;
}


// ----------------------------------------------
// physics/motion methods
// ----------------------------------------------



/**
 *  Set acceleration of this object.
 *  @param acc Acceleration in (pixels/second) per second.
 */
public void setAcceleration(float acc)
{
    acceleration = acc;
}

/**
 *  Set deceleration of this object.
 *  Deceleration is only applied when object is not accelerating.
 *  @param dec Deceleration in (pixels/second) per second.
 */


public void setDeceleration(float dec)
{

    deceleration = dec;
}

/**
 *  Set maximum speed of this object.
 *  @param ms Maximum speed of this object in (pixels/second).
 */
public void setMaxSpeed(float ms)
{

    maxSpeed = ms;
}

/**
 *  Set the speed of movement (in pixels/second) in current direction.
 *  If current speed is zero (direction is undefined), direction will be set to 0 degrees.
 *  @param speed of movement (pixels/second)
 */
public void setSpeed(float speed)
{
    // if length is zero, then assume motion angle is zero degrees
    if (velocityVec.len() == 0)
        velocityVec.set(speed, 0);
    else
        velocityVec.setLength(speed);
}

/**
 *  Calculates the speed of movement (in pixels/second).
 *  @return speed of movement (pixels/second)
 */
public float getSpeed()
{
    return velocityVec.len();
}



/**
 *  Determines if this object is moving (if speed is greater than zero).
 *  @return false when speed is zero, true otherwise
 */
public boolean isMoving()
{
    return (getSpeed() > 0);
}


/**
 *  Sets the angle of motion (in degrees).
 *  If current speed is zero, this will have no effect.
 *  @param angle of motion (degrees)
 */
public void setMotionAngle(float angle)
{
    velocityVec.setAngle(angle);
}

/**
 *  Get the angle of motion (in degrees), calculated from the velocity vector.
 *  <br>
 *  To align actor image angle with motion angle, use <code>setRotation( getMotionAngle() )</code>.
 *  @return angle of motion (degrees)
 */
public float getMotionAngle()
{
    return velocityVec.angle();
}

/**
 *  Update accelerate vector by angle and value stored in acceleration field.
 *  Acceleration is applied by <code>applyPhysics</code> method.
 *  @param angle Angle (degrees) in which to accelerate.
 *  @see #acceleration
 *  @see #applyPhysics
 */
public void accelerateAtAngle(float angle)
{
    accelerationVec.add( 
        new Vector2(acceleration, 0).setAngle(angle) );
}

/**
 *  Update accelerate vector by current rotation angle and value stored in acceleration field.
 *  Acceleration is applied by <code>applyPhysics</code> method.
 *  @see #acceleration
 *  @see #applyPhysics
 */
public void accelerateForward()
{
    accelerateAtAngle( getRotation() );
}

/**
 *  Adjust velocity vector based on acceleration vector, 
 *  then adjust position based on velocity vector. <br>
 *  If not accelerating, deceleration value is applied. <br>
 *  Speed is limited by maxSpeed value. <br>
 *  Acceleration vector reset to (0,0) at end of method. <br>
 *  @param dt Time elapsed since previous frame (delta time); typically obtained from <code>act</code> method.
 *  @see #acceleration
 *  @see #deceleration
 *  @see #maxSpeed
 */
public void applyPhysics(float dt)
{
    // apply acceleration
    velocityVec.add( accelerationVec.x * dt, accelerationVec.y * dt );

    float speed = getSpeed();

    // decrease speed (decelerate) when not accelerating
    if (accelerationVec.len() == 0)
        speed -= deceleration * dt;

    // keep speed within set bounds
    speed = MathUtils.clamp(speed, 0, maxSpeed);

    // update velocity
    setSpeed(speed);

    // update position according to value stored in velocity vector
    moveBy( velocityVec.x * dt, velocityVec.y * dt );

    // reset acceleration
    accelerationVec.set(0,0);


}

// ----------------------------------------------
// Collision polygon methods
// ----------------------------------------------

/**
 *  Set rectangular-shaped collision polygon.
 *  This method is automatically called when animation is set,
 *   provided that the current boundary polygon is null.
 *  @see #setAnimation
 */
public void setBoundaryRectangle()
{
    float w = getWidth();
    float h = getHeight(); 

    float[] vertices = {0,0, w,0, w,h, 0,h};
    boundaryPolygon = new Polygon(vertices);
}

/**
 *  Replace default (rectangle) collision polygon with an n-sided polygon. <br>
 *  Vertices of polygon lie on the ellipse contained within bounding rectangle.
 *  Note: one vertex will be located at point (0,width);
 *  a 4-sided polygon will appear in the orientation of a diamond.
 *  @param numSides number of sides of the collision polygon
 */
public void setBoundaryPolygon(int numSides)
{
    float w = getWidth();
    float h = getHeight();

    float[] vertices = new float[2*numSides];
    for (int i = 0; i < numSides; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * 6.28f / numSides;
        // x-coordinate
        vertices[2*i] = w/2 * MathUtils.cos(angle) + w/2;
        // y-coordinate
        vertices[2*i+1] = h/2 * MathUtils.sin(angle) + h/2;
    }
    boundaryPolygon = new Polygon(vertices);

}

/**
 *  Returns bounding polygon for this BaseActor, adjusted by Actor's current position and rotation.
 *  @return bounding polygon for this BaseActor
 */
public Polygon getBoundaryPolygon()
{
    boundaryPolygon.setPosition( getX(), getY() );
    boundaryPolygon.setOrigin( getOriginX(), getOriginY() );
    boundaryPolygon.setRotation( getRotation() );
    boundaryPolygon.setScale( getScaleX(), getScaleY() );        
    return boundaryPolygon;
}

/**
 *  Determine if this BaseActor overlaps other BaseActor (according to collision polygons).
 *  @param other BaseActor to check for overlap
 *  @return true if collision polygons of this and other BaseActor overlap
 *  @see #setBoundaryRectangle
 *  @see #setBoundaryPolygon
 */
public boolean overlaps(BaseActor other)
{
    Polygon poly1 = this.getBoundaryPolygon();
    Polygon poly2 = other.getBoundaryPolygon();

    // initial test to improve performance
    if ( !poly1.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(poly2.getBoundingRectangle()) )
        return false;

    return Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons( poly1, poly2 );
}

/**
 *  Implement a "solid"-like behavior:
 *  when there is overlap, move this BaseActor away from other BaseActor
 *  along minimum translation vector until there is no overlap.
 *  @param other BaseActor to check for overlap
 *  @return direction vector by which actor was translated, null if no overlap
 */
public Vector2 preventOverlap(BaseActor other)
{
    Polygon poly1 = this.getBoundaryPolygon();
    Polygon poly2 = other.getBoundaryPolygon();

    // initial test to improve performance
    if ( !poly1.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(poly2.getBoundingRectangle()) )
        return null;

    MinimumTranslationVector mtv = new MinimumTranslationVector();
    boolean polygonOverlap = Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(poly1, poly2, mtv);

    if ( !polygonOverlap )
        return null;

    this.moveBy( mtv.normal.x * mtv.depth, mtv.normal.y * mtv.depth );
    return mtv.normal;
}

/**
 *  Determine if this BaseActor is near other BaseActor (according to collision polygons).
 *  @param distance amount (pixels) by which to enlarge collision polygon width and height 
 *  @param other BaseActor to check if nearby
 *  @return true if collision polygons of this (enlarged) and other BaseActor overlap
 *  @see #setBoundaryRectangle
 *  @see #setBoundaryPolygon
 */
public boolean isWithinDistance(float distance, BaseActor other)
{
    Polygon poly1 = this.getBoundaryPolygon();
    float scaleX = (this.getWidth() + 2 * distance) / this.getWidth();
    float scaleY = (this.getHeight() + 2 * distance) / this.getHeight();
    poly1.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

    Polygon poly2 = other.getBoundaryPolygon();

    // initial test to improve performance
    if ( !poly1.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(poly2.getBoundingRectangle()) )
        return false;

    return Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons( poly1, poly2 );
}

/**
 *  Set world dimensions for use by methods boundToWorld() and scrollTo().
 *  @param width width of world
 *  @param height height of world
 */
public static void setWorldBounds(float width, float height)
{
    worldBounds = new Rectangle( 0,0, width, height );
}   

/**
 *  Set world dimensions for use by methods boundToWorld() and scrollTo().
 * // @param BaseActor whose size determines the world bounds (typically a background image)
 */
public static void setWorldBounds(BaseActor ba)
{
    setWorldBounds( ba.getWidth(), ba.getHeight() );
}   

/**
 *  Get world dimensions
 *  @return Rectangle whose width/height represent world bounds
 */
public static Rectangle getWorldBounds()
{
    return worldBounds;
}   

/**
 * If an edge of an object moves past the world bounds, 
 *   adjust its position to keep it completely on screen.
 */
public void boundToWorld()
{
    if (getX() < 0)
        setX(0);
    if (getX() + getWidth() > worldBounds.width)    
        setX(worldBounds.width - getWidth());
    if (getY() < 0)
        setY(0);
    if (getY() + getHeight() > worldBounds.height)
        setY(worldBounds.height - getHeight());
}

/**
 *  Center camera on this object, while keeping camera's range of view 
 *  (determined by screen size) completely within world bounds.
 */
public void alignCamera()
{
    Camera cam = this.getStage().getCamera();
    Viewport v = this.getStage().getViewport();

    // center camera on actor
    cam.position.set( this.getX() + this.getOriginX(), this.getY() + this.getOriginY(), 0 );

    // bound camera to layout
    cam.position.x = MathUtils.clamp(cam.position.x, cam.viewportWidth/2,  worldBounds.width -  cam.viewportWidth/2);
    cam.position.y = MathUtils.clamp(cam.position.y, cam.viewportHeight/2, worldBounds.height - cam.viewportHeight/2);
    cam.update();
}

// ----------------------------------------------
// Instance list methods
// ----------------------------------------------

/**
 *  Retrieves a list of all instances of the object from the given stage with the given class name
 *      or whose class extends the class with the given name.
 *  If no instances exist, returns an empty list.
 *  Useful when coding interactions between different types of game objects in update method.
 *  @param stage Stage containing BaseActor instances
 *  @param className name of a class that extends the BaseActor class
 *  @return list of instances of the object in stage which extend with the given class name 
 */
public static ArrayList<BaseActor> getList(Stage stage, String className)
{
    ArrayList<BaseActor> list = new ArrayList<BaseActor>();

    Class theClass = null;
    try
    {  theClass = Class.forName(className);  }
    catch (Exception error)
    {  error.printStackTrace();  }

    for (Actor a : stage.getActors())
    {
        if ( theClass.isInstance( a ) )
            list.add( (BaseActor)a );
    }

    return list;
}



/**
 *  Returns number of instances of a given class (that extends BaseActor).
 *  @param className name of a class that extends the BaseActor class
 *  @return number of instances of the class
 */
public static int count(Stage stage, String className)
{
    return getList(stage, className).size();
}

// ----------------------------------------------
// Actor methods: act and draw
// ----------------------------------------------

/**
 *  Processes all Actions and related code for this object; 
 *  automatically called by act method in Stage class.
 *  @param dt elapsed time (second) since last frame (supplied by Stage act method)
 */
public void act(float dt)
{
    super.act( dt );

    if (!animationPaused)
        elapsedTime += dt;
}

/**
 *  Draws current frame of animation; automatically called by draw method in Stage class. <br>
 *  If color has been set, image will be tinted by that color. <br>
 *  If no animation has been set or object is invisible, nothing will be drawn.
 *  @param batch (supplied by Stage draw method)
 *  @param parentAlpha (supplied by Stage draw method)
 *  @see #setColor
 *  @see #setVisible
 *  
 */
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) 
{

    // apply color tint effect
    Color c = getColor(); 
    batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a);

    if ( animation != null && isVisible() )
        batch.draw( animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime), 
            getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
            getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation() );

    super.draw( batch, parentAlpha );
}
```

}

I don't use all the methods in the BaseActor class. I took it from a book and now use it in my work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all the ins and outs of this class and the physics system you're using, I can only explain in general terms. You are describing two different things:

1. Lasers move continuously.
2. A new laser should appear at the home position once per second.

And a third thing (I'm assuming) is that the laser should disappear at some point, because otherwise you will have a continuously increasing number of lasers forever.

There are two different ways to implement point 1.

a. Override the `act()` method and update the rotation from there. Something like:

```
public void act(float delta){
    super.act(delta);
    setRotation(getRotation() + DEGREES_PER_SECOND * delta;
}
```

b. Use a series of Actions. I don't know how far you want it to rotate, but for example, you could put this in the constructor:

```
addAction(Actions.rotateBy(270f, 3f, Interpolation.linear); // rotate 270 degrees in 3 seconds
```

For the second task, you can set up a repeating action that does it:

```
stage.addAction(Actions.repeat(Actions.run { new Runnable{ 
    public void run() {
        addActor(generateNewLaser()); 
    }
));
```

where `generateNewLaser()` would create the new Laser instance and associated physics setup. The above is simplified. In practice you probably would want to keep a member reference to this Action so you can cancel it in response to something happening in your game.

Or you can handle the logic manually in your `render()` method or with other classes that manager your Laser system, or something.

Comment: I just want to mention, I don't use Stage and Actors for anything besides the UI. I find that it takes more time to conform my design to the existing Actor class and behavior than it does to build my own simpler system of game objects.